# ROLLBACK DDL commands in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl, rollback

I have found a lot of threads about rolling back DDL command within transaction in SQL Server, but I am wondering, which DDL statements are transactional and which are not? Is there a comprehensive list or general rule in the documentation?

Comment: All DDL commands that can be run in transaction can be rollbacked. I think stuff that cannot be run in transaction is CREATE DATABASE and BACKUP/RESTORE, not sure there's a comprehensive list, nor do i not know why you want to know? Just do what you want to do and see if it works

Comment: Just to make mu sure :)
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis
"SQL Server supports transactional DDL in some cases. If you are running SQL Server in read-committed isolation mode (pessimistic), which is the default mode, you are able to use transactional DDL SQL Server supports transactional DDL. If you're running SQL Server 2005 or greater and running in a snapshot isolation mode (optimistic) there're restrictions to what DDL is supported in an explicit transaction SQL Server snapshot isolation transactional DDL constraints."

Comment: In the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#starting-transactions "You can use all Transact-SQL statements in an explicit transaction, except for the following statements:  `CREATE DATABASE` `ALTER DATABASE` `DROP DATABASE` `CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG` `ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG` `DROP FULLTEXT CATALOG` `DROP FULLTEXT INDEX` `ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX` `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX` `BACKUP` `RESTORE` `RECONFIGURE` Full-text system stored procedures; `sp_dboption` inside explicit or implicit transactions."

Comment: The logic behind it is: you can do anything transactional, as long as it isn't affecting the fundamentals existence of the database. Hence you can't create, alter, drop, backup or restore, and changing server options. I'm not sure the logic behind the Full-Text restrictions though.

Comment: @Charlieface Probably that it makes changes to file system and/or registry, and doesn't have the ability to keep the "before" versions.